# Regular Expression Match for Password

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm building a form in ASP.Net using VB and I have a text box that I'd like to validate against the following rules:

- Must be 6 - 20 characters long
- Can Contain Letters and Could Be ALL letters
- Can Contain The Following Special Characters: `!@#$%^&*+-=(){}:;,'./?`
- Cannot contain any whitespace.
- Cannot be all numbers and does not REQUIRE a number
- The case does not matter

Those requirements aren't set by me...That's just what I have to work with.

So, the following would match:

```
TestUserPass
Te$tU$e^p@%}
testuserpass
test{user}n@ame
```

The following would not match:

```
8392039
dhj#5|3j
```

Hopefully that gives an idea of what I'm looking for...

Here's what I have so far: `\b[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^&\*\+=\(\){}:;,'\./\?-]{6,20}\b`

I believe that's working for everything EXCEPT the invalidating the instance where the entry is all numbers.  It's the all numbers portion that I've been struggling with, though perhaps someone will find a flaw in what I already have.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not have a separate regex for each rule?

Comment: So your question is: how to find if a string exists of numbers only. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Greg I could have done that, but I was hoping for the simplicity of one expression and one validation control.  Thanks for the constructive question though!

Comment: @CodeCaster That wasn't quite what my question was.  I knew how to match a string of numbers only...my question was how to combine that with what I already had.  In this case it was the negative lookahead assertion that I needed help with.  This was my first question posted here so I apologize if it wasn't clear enough or if I didn't demonstrate having done some research first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different anchors, and you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that other characters than digits are present:

```
^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%^&*+=(){}:;,'./?-]{6,20}$
```

Also, you don't need to escape (most) regex metacharacters within a character class as they don't have a special meaning there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and a working regular expression.  More importantly, thanks for the explanation of why it works and what I was missing before and how to tweak what I already had.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*+=(){}:;,'./?-]{6,20}$
 --------                                
     |
     |->dont match further if all are digits
```

`-` within character class represents a range and should be either escaped or should be at the beginning or at the end...

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Your RegEx worked perfectly as did Tim's.